# Select one table column with distinct record with other table all data

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have 2 table 'userfoodcategory' and 'MenuMaster'.

'userfoodcategory' has the foodcategory and 'MenuMaster' has multiple items along with this category with a column 'isnonveg'.

I want to query 'userfoodcategory' table data with 1 addition column 'isnonveg', this column is in 'MenuMaster' table.

I am trying below query but it is giving redundant record

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ufc.*, MM.isnonveg
FROM   MenuMaster MM
LEFT JOIN  userfoodcategory ufc  ON MM.categoryid = ufc.foodcategoryid
WHERE  ufc.USERID = 19 --and MM.isnonveg IS NULL
order by ufc.foodcategoryid
```

For more details please have a look on below screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Also I want this as a linq query, but first I was trying to build it in sql and after that I need to convert it in linq as I am new in linq.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you add an example of data and output you expect from the query ?
have you tried using "and MM.isnonveg IS NULL" as a join condition (putting it after "ON MM.categoryid = ufc.foodcategoryid") instead of in the "where" ?

Comment: Thanks @JulienR, I just want 'isnonveg' column showing in second screen shot, with data showing in first screen screen shot. Means with first screen shot data, I need addition column 'isnonveg' and this column is in 'MenuMaster' table.

Comment: sorry, can't access screenshots because of restrictions from my workplace

Comment: Well, since you have a lot of different rows is `MenuMaster` for each category, and every one of this row might have either 0 or 1 in the `IsNonVeg` table, it's only natural to have multiple values for each Cateroty. What value would you like to get back in the select statement if both options exists?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, no for each category isnonveg will have only 0 or 1. Not both for 1 category in MenuMaster.

Comment: Well in that case I don't see why the query in your question should give multiple results for categories. Also, if there can only be one value for each category, then this column is probably on the wrong table and should be on the categories table.

Comment: btw, what version of sql server are you actually working with? Please remove the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use below Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ufc.*, MM.isnonveg
FROM  (select distinct categoryid,isnonveg FROM MenuMaster) MM
LEFT JOIN  userfoodcategory ufc  ON MM.categoryid = ufc.foodcategoryid
WHERE  ufc.USERID = 19 --and MM.isnonveg IS NULL
order by ufc.foodcategoryid
```

Comment: Thanks @Sujith, its working now, I just need to add 1 more condition 'and MM.isnonveg =0'. Now I want this in Linq.

Comment: @AnandSystematix WC. Please mark as answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: marked it as answer, just 1 more thing, I need this in Linq statement, can you please help?

Comment: @AnandSystematix Sorry I am not that great with LINQ. I will need to spend some time to modify this into LINQ. Can you try http://www.linqpad.net/ . It would give you the required query in LINQ from SQL

Comment: I just tried to build this into LINQ. Try using this : FROM m in 
(
FROM menu in MenuMaster 
           select new 
              {
                 categoryid = menu.categoryid,
                 isnonveg = menu.isnonveg
                
              })        
              .Distinct()

)
join ufc in 
    userfoodcategory.DefaultIfEmpty()
on m.categoryid = ufc.foodcategoryid
where ufc.USERID = 19
select new { ufc, m.isnonveg }

Comment: @AnandSystematix You may need to check the above LINQ and correct if there are any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it .